# How to set wallpapers use app-services Wallpaper and Contact photo?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, intentservice, wallpaper

I use this code below, but it works partly - set wallpapers only on my real device api23 nexus5, in another devices in no way not setting. Also cant set wallpapers to icon of contact.

My actions:

- tap button set wallpaper
- in the opened window select service:

if choosed 'Contact photo' - open the service and if choose any contact

- Actual result: just return to my wallpapers app without set
- Expected result: must open 'crop picture' the image and then tap to set this image to contact icon.

if choosed 'Wallpaper'

- Actual reuslt: just return to my wallpapers app without set and show message 'Can not load the image'(work only api 23 on my Nexus5)
- Expected result: open the service and tap to set

  ```
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA); // attach services
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
          file = new File(getFolderStorageDirectory(), getFileName()); // create temp file
          if (isExternalStorageWritable()) { // check whether available external storage
              try {
                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // write image
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Log.e(TAG, "File not saved");
              }
          } else {
              showToast(getString(R.string.sd_card));
          }
          intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
          intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
          intent.putExtra("jpg", "image/*");
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select service:"));
  ```

Why not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Instead

`intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");`

use

`setAs.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mFile), "image/*");` and it will work.

All code:

```
private void setAsUseServices() {
        onCreateFileListener(); // here will create file e.g. in Picture directory
        Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        setAs.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        Uri sourceUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
        setAs.setDataAndType(sourceUri, "image/*");
        setAs.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
        setAs.putExtra("save_path", sourceUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Select service:"));
    }
```